# Conditional probability to be calculated but I'm not able to solve the first part of the question

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, conditional

Suppose that a box contains one blue card and four red cards. The red cards are labelled $X$, $Y$ , $Z$, and $W$. Suppose also that two of these five cards are selected at random, without replacement.

1. If it is known that card $X$ has been selected, what is the probability that both cards are red?
2. If it is known that at least one red card has been selected, what is the probability that both cards are red?

*I'm not able to solve the first part $P(i) = 3/4$ but idk how like help.*

Comment: You have five cards overall, and you label them with four letters? Is $X$ a red card? What in $i$ in $P(i)$?

Comment: Nikhil, I have edited the question to make "The red cards are labelled X, Y , Z, and W." more salient (initially I thought/interpreted that the blue one could just as well be labeled with X, Y, Z, or W). I guess that this was the intention of the question, or otherwise I do not see how we can get 3/4.

Comment: yeah my professor didn't write the question properly and initially I also assumed that it was likely that the blue card could be labelled. But now I've got it thanks!

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us what you understand thus far, what 
you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to 
help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you 
is grounds for closing.

Answer (score 1):

Can you at least make a *list* of possible two-card sets from five cards labeled $B, W, X, Y, Z$?  Hint: There are only ten such sets; you find more than ten, check for duplicates in your list, and remember that $\{B,X\}$ is the same set as $\{X,B\}$. How many of these two-card sets on your list include $X$ as one of the cards? How many of these two-card sets that include $X$ on your (hopefully shorter) list consist of two red cards? Hint: one of the cards must be $X$; what is the other **red** card?

Comment: yay! got the answer thanks!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on *how* we got to know that card X is among the two cards.

Like Dilip Sarwate's answer (+1) we can enumerate the different sets with an X in it (and make it a combinatorial problem), but we do not know how the sets arise and whether they have equal probabilities conditional on X being in the set.

For example, it could be that always a random labeled (red) card from the two selected cards is revealed (whether it is X or not). It just happens that it contains an X but it could have been another letter. If the X occurs among the two selected cards while one of them is a blue card, then it is more likely that it gets revealed (because it is the only labeled card). This makes the problem related to the [Monty Hall problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monty_Hall_problem).

This is an example that shows that we need to know the entire process that generates the data and information. Just a conditional statement, without context, is not enough.